# karma/jasmine/angular toHaveBeenCalledWith is really called

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

in  my app for instance I've got

```
$rootScope.$emit('loggedin',data.user);
$rootScope.$on('loggedin', function(event,user) {
    console.log('called');           
});
```

in my test

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$emit');

var response = {
    "success":1,
    "user":{
        "id":1,
        "email":"lama@test.test",
        "fullname":"Lama user",
        "username":"lamauser",
        "groups":["Users"]
    },
    "logged":1
};
$httpBackend.when('POST', '/api/v1/user').respond(200,response);
$scope.save();
$httpBackend.flush();
expect($scope.errors.length).toEqual(0);
expect($rootScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('loggedin',response.user);
```

both the app and test works well
but in the test I never see the console message
*called*

so I'm wondering if during the test $on is never triggered 
or I miss something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the real `$emit()` to be called, you have to set it explicitly after `spyOn` like this:

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$emit').and.callThrough();
```

Or in Jasmine 1.3:

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$emit').andCallThrough();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just tried with .andCallThrough(); but I keep on not to see 'called'

Comment: mmm it seems there is a $rootScope issue because if I put the $on listener in a run block it works

Comment: Is your `$emit` and `$on` are really in that order? If yes, that is the cause, you are trying to emit an event before subscribe for it. Try move `$on` up to before `$emit`.

Comment: I've got $on in a separate controller the $emit in a controller attach to a route. I don't understand why it works in the app and not in the test

Comment: It seems your `separate controller` is not initialzed in the test. If you want to test it, you have to somehow make it to be initialized.

Comment: yeah but I've to find yet how :)

Comment: In a unit test you should test only one unit at a time - this means only one controller. Write one test which tests that the first controller emits and another test that the other controller listens.